# How to read data from one child (Firebase Database) Xcode

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase

I am currently working on an app where I have a load of reports that have been entered in my Firebase database, which I need to access in Xcode, then display onto a TableView.
The issue that I am running into is that I have the database set up os that the reports are kept as Child nodes in the Reports tab, however I have them set so that they all have nodes going off of them explaining what the report was about. I currently have a section of code that will allow me to read all of the child nodes off of the main Reports node, yet I cannot get it to read the ones that further details nested inside of the Reports tab. (Apologize if I don't explain it much it is hard to wrap my head around it!)
The code that I currently have is this:

```
var subData = [String]()
//tableView is the table

//Below is inside the ViewDidLoad section
ref = Database.database().reference().child("Reports")
handle = ref?.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    let Report = snapshot.value as? String
    if let actualReport = Report {
        self.subData.append(actualReport)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

[Image of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N6lj.png)

And here is an image of my database, of which only number 1 shows up on the tableview when I want all of the other nodes to show up instead.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this

```
firestore.collection("yourCollectionName").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to migrate my data from a realtime database to a Firestore one? Also I don't have anything other than Firebase and Firebase/Database installed, so it doesn't recognise the firestore command. Also, would this replace the handle = ref?.xxx line?

Comment: Yes, if you use the Firestore your data is come automatically when added data. But in your case  you can change "tableview.reloadData()" line's position. I advise use Firestore even so.
You can review this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart